# Keeping multitrack files online

Tags: daw

I'm in the middle or recording an album, and my bandmate is in the next county. I'm currently using box.net to share mixes with him, but I have no easy way of sharing the multitrack files.

I've got notes on the mixes on text files in the same folders as the files, and it'd be great if we could share those as well. (Of course, we'd actually work on them on a local drive.)

Does anyone know of a free or cheap FTP or backup site that'll take files up to 200 - 300 megabytes?

Now for the part that's music-specific: If there were some way to keep mix notes online, something faster than, say, Google Documents, that would make this whole thing easier.

(It's possible this belongs on SuperUser or the Web Apps site, but I'd like to hear what audio folk have to say about this.)

Comment: Is your bandmate modifying the multitrack files and/or the notes?

Comment: He'd like to be able to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[DropBox](http://www.dropbox.com/) could probably used to accomplish this.  You can use up to 2 gigs for free, and it works on Windows, Mac, and Linux.

This would allow either of you to modify your notes and the changes would automatically be snynched to the other's computer.

You can also check out some of the alternatives listed in [this article](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=2149).

Comment: Dropbox doesn't seem to like garageband files. When I put them in my desktop dropbox, the files on the server are significantly smaller than the local files. The web client doesn't like them at all, the uploader page is returning an error, and the "simple uploader" just freezes. I'll try again tomorow.

Comment: Looks like other people have used it with garageband... http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=2149

Comment: GarageBand uses what's called an OSX Package file, non-Macs tend to not understand them. Zipping the file seems to be doing the trick.

Comment: @neilfein: ah, good find.

Comment: Dropbox is incredible for this kind of work. Works fine with Logic Pro.

Comment: @Redbeard - If I had the money, that's what I'd be using now.

Comment: Up vote for Dropbox. Me and the band mates have been using this for well over a year to share Logic Pro projects. Works very well. Key to success: don't work with the original in Dropbox, make a copy, copy it back when you're done. Requires some co-ordination between people so you don't clobber changes from others.

Comment: @Redbeard - And that's what I just made the jump to.